# Why can I create an instance of a class without storing it to a variable and still have everything work?

Tags: c#, class, variables, instance

I have a non-static class called `ImplementHeaderButtons` which contains a non-static public method called `Implement`. The name of the class and method are not important, what's important is that they are not static, so they need to be instantiated in order to be used, right?

So I used to do this:

```
var implementHeaderButtons = new ImplementHeaderButtons();
implementHeaderButtons.Implement(this, headerButtons);
```

But then I decided to play around a bit with it (actually I was looking for a way to make it a one-liner) and I concluded that the following code works just as well:

```
new ImplementHeaderButtons().Implement(this, headerButtons);
```

Now, I do not need a variable to hold the instance, but my question is: **how come I can create a new instance of a class on the fly and call a method of it without having a variable to store the instance?**

I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work as intended, but it does.

Comment: I am actually confused as to why you think it wouldn't work.

Comment: @KirkWoll I guess I was confused because I wasn't smart enough to think through it by myself, haha.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> they are not static, so they need to be instantiated in order to be used, right?

Yes, but you are still instantiating the class with `new ImplementHeaderButtons()`, you just aren't storing a reference to that newly created instance anywhere.

You can still call a method on this instance as you have done in your example, but you will not be able to do anything else with it afterwards without a reference. Eventually the instance will be cleaned up by the garbage collector (provided the method you call does not store a reference to the object somewhere).

Comment: So it is like it lives just as long as the called method does its job and then it gets cleaned up?

Comment: @IneedHelp Yup, so long as in that method it doesn't produce additional references to itself (say registering event handlers to certain non-expiring application events)

Comment: Yep, just so. Actually it gets cleaned up when garbage collector starts working AND if Implement() method did not save the reference to the object elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is just a reference, for your convenience. You are not naming it, but it is just there, on the top of the stack (in general ;-) ). Do you can call it's methods as long as you can refer to the variable, either by using it's name (which you do not have) or by working on the "unnamed" object you've just created.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `new ImplementHeaderButtons()` returns an instance of ImplementHeaderButtons. Then, you call `.Implement()` on that instance.

Think of it like this:

```
(new ImplementHeaderButtons()).Implement(this, headerButtons);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried first and then decided to try without the parentheses. But for some reason I was wondering how does it work without actually storing the instance. I learned now that it is like a temporary variable.