# Is it ok to create an instance of a class and call a function with creating an object?

Tags: c#, oop

Is there any thing i need to be aware of when doing this :-

```
new Emailer().SendAlert("Message");
```

instead of

```
Emailer oEmail = new Emailer();
oEmail.SendAlert("Message");
oEmail = null;
```

I presume it both cases, both will be cleaned up using the garbage collection and not consume memory.

I do not want to use the static key word because its being called in object instances and don't want possible pollution.

If its just personal choice how its done then thats the answer.

Comment: This is more for something like a code review, but both will be collected. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557603/why-can-i-create-an-instance-of-a-class-without-storing-it-to-a-variable-and-sti

Comment: Read the duplicate's answer. Directly from the C# core engineering master